# Пытаюсь сделать анализ настроения с нейросетью по статье - выходит Ексепшн

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, нейронные-сети, keras

Делаю анализ настроения комментариев по статье сайта.Код до эксепшена:

```
# %%
import os

import numpy as np

# For DataFrame object
import pandas as pd

# Neural Network
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from keras.optimizers import RMSprop

# Text Vectorizing
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer

# Train-test-split
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# History visualization
# %matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Normalize
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize

# %%

# %%
# switch to google colab
flag_google_colab = False
# /switch to google colab
 
if flag_google_colab:
    from google.colab import drive
    drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
    google_colab_prefix_data_folder = '/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/'  
else:
    google_colab_prefix_data_folder = ''
 
fold_csv = google_colab_prefix_data_folder + 'data/labeled.csv'
fpickle = google_colab_prefix_data_folder + 'learned.pkl'

# %%
df = pd.read_csv(fold_csv)
print(df.head())

# %%
# Теперь удалим символы новой строки из текстовых данных
def delete_new_line_symbols(text):
    text = text.replace('\n', ' ')
    return text

df['comment'] = df['comment'].apply(delete_new_line_symbols)
print(df.head())    
# %%
# Приведем колонку toxic к целочисленному виду
target = np.array(df['toxic'].astype('uint8'))

# %%
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=50000, 
                      filters='!"#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~\t\n', 
                      lower=True, 
                      split=' ', 
                      char_level=False)
#print(Tokenizer.__doc__)
"""
Text tokenization utility class.

    This class allows to vectorize a text corpus, by turning each
    text into either a sequence of integers (each integer being the index
    of a token in a dictionary) or into a vector where the coefficient
    for each token could be binary, based on word count, based on tf-idf...

    # Arguments
        num_words: the maximum number of words to keep, based
            on word frequency. Only the most common `num_words` words will
            be kept.
        filters: a string where each element is a character that will be
            filtered from the texts. The default is all punctuation, plus
            tabs and line breaks, minus the `'` character.
        lower: boolean. Whether to convert the texts to lowercase.
        split: str. Separator for word splitting.
        char_level: if True, every character will be treated as a token.
        oov_token: if given, it will be added to word_index and used to
            replace out-of-vocabulary words during text_to_sequence calls

    By default, all punctuation is removed, turning the texts into
    space-separated sequences of words
    (words maybe include the `'` character). These sequences are then
    split into lists of tokens. They will then be indexed or vectorized.

    `0` is a reserved index that won't be assigned to any word.
"""                          

# %%
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(df['comment'])
matrix = tokenizer.texts_to_matrix(df['comment'].to_numpy(), mode='count')
```

На последенй строчке эксепшн, что то о большом массиве:
ValueError: array is too big; `arr.size * arr.dtype.itemsize` is larger than the maximum possible size.

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
d:\user_win_home\code\python_new4\analiz_nastr\app.py in <module>
      97 tokenizer.fit_on_texts(df['comment'])
----> 98 matrix = tokenizer.texts_to_matrix(df['comment'].to_numpy(), mode='count')
      99 """
      100 binary — вернёт массив, состоящий из 0 и 1, где каждый флаг будет отвечать за то, присутствует определённое слово в тексте.
      101 count — простой счетчик слов

D:\user_win_home\code\python_new3\test_keras_gensim\envs\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\text.py in texts_to_matrix(self, texts, mode)
    374         """
    375         sequences = self.texts_to_sequences(texts)
--> 376         return self.sequences_to_matrix(sequences, mode=mode)
    377 
    378     def sequences_to_matrix(self, sequences, mode='binary'):

D:\user_win_home\code\python_new3\test_keras_gensim\envs\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\text.py in sequences_to_matrix(self, sequences, mode)
    404                              'before using tfidf mode.')
    405 
--> 406         x = np.zeros((len(sequences), num_words))
    407         for i, seq in enumerate(sequences):
    408             if not seq:

ValueError: array is too big; `arr.size * arr.dtype.itemsize` is larger than the maximum possible size.
```

Как это решить, исправить?

Comment: А в цифрах, каков размер массива, который "too big" -  вы проверяли?

Comment: len(df['comment']) дает 14 412

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так понимаю, вы пытаетесь из разреженных матриц сделать обычные. Не знаю как работают с текстами в `Keras` и нейросетях вообще, но вообще говоря такое делать не нужно - после токенизации могут получиться миллионы (ну или как минимум десятки тысяч) фич/столбцов. Держать в памяти обычные матрицы такого размера, учитывая что и сэмплов тоже могут быть миллионы - нереально. Да и обрабатывать такие объёмы будет невозможно. Работайте непосредственно с разреженными матрицами, модели `Scikit-learn` это умеют, наверняка и `Keras` тоже должен уметь. Либо сильно ограничивайте число выходных признаков при токенизации, но будьте тогда готовы и к возможному сильному падению качества. Можно ещё попробовать понизить размерность данных после токенизации с помощью `PCA`, это может и не сильно ударить по качеству, если повезёт. Но в `PCA` опять же нужно передавать разреженную матрицу после токенизации.

Возможно, в `Keras` нужно смотреть в сторону каких-то генераторов и батчей. Например, там есть в токенизаторе `texts_to_sequences_generator`. Генераторы обрабатывают данные "на лету" и не потребляют столько памяти, сколько готовые данные полного объёма.

Comment: Скажите, вот я хочу научится работать с текстом вместе с нейросетями, поэтому выбрал эту статью с сайта.Может быть у вас есть ссылки, где это относительно просто можно делать с sklearn и нейросетями?Так трудновато дается понимание перевода текста в числа.PS.Да автор говорит что получается 30 000 признаков(фич).

Comment: @Константин Мне кажется лучше начать без нейросетей. Когда разберётесь с подготовкой данных - тогда уже переходить к нейросетям. Вот тут по шагам прямо расписано и можно по быстрому всё попробовать. Лучше двигаться небольшими шагами, но всё понимать. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html